# passing php value into a href tag html

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, download

I want to download file from database, but I have a condition. Every file has unique `request_id` , that is from table. These codes below downloaded file from the last `request_id`. For instance, when I click download button from different `request_id`, it gives me like this (in the download history foder) :

1. excel3.xlsx
2. excel3(1).xlsx
3. excel3(2).xlsx

It should be :

1. excel1.xlsx
2. excel2.xlsx
3. excel3.xlsx

And the downloaded file is ZERO BYTE. I cannot find my mistake since there is no error shown. Please help...

**Download button:**

```
<a href="<?php echo site_url('admin/download')?>" download>
  <button id="upload_excel" type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value=<?php echo $value['req']?>>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope" aria-hidden="true" ></span> Download
  </button>
```

**My controller:**

```
function download($req)
        {
            $this->load->helper('download');

            $this->load->model('request');
            $data['file'] = $this->request->request($req);
            foreach ($data['file'] as $key) 
            {
                $req_id = $key['req'];
                $data['file'][$req_id] = $key['filename_user'];
                $file = $data['file'][$req_id];

                $download_file = FCPATH.'/kirim_undangan/';//path of the file
                $content_type = mime_content_type($download_file);//mime type of the file
                $file_name = basename($file);//file name based on request_id 
                header("Pragma: public");
                header("Expires: 0");
                header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
                header("Cache-Control: public");
                header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
                header("Content-type: ".$content_type);
                header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$file_name."\"");
                header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
                header("Content-Length: ".filesize($download_file));

                    while (ob_get_level()) {
                       ob_end_clean();
                    }
                readfile($download_file);
            }
        }
```

**My model:**

```
function request()
    {

        $this->db->select("request_Id as req, email as email, name as nama, phone as phone, address as alamat_pengirim, filename_user, filename_admin");
        $this->db->where('status < 3');
        $query  =   $this->db->get('request');
        return $query->result_array();
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried var dumping the $download_file? Also check the the value in the download button is not empty..

Comment: yes, the `$value['req]` contains the `request_id`. Where should I put the `var_dump` you suggest me?

Comment: just before the readfile($download_file); line.. var_dump the $download_file

Comment: Put `var_dump($data['file']);exit;` just before `foreach` loop to see what structure of array you have there. Post that result in question (just two array elements will be sufficient if there is many more).